# Defining multiple image variables as markers

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps, if-statement, google-maps-markers

I can't find a simple answer to this anywhere.
I'm looking to define more than one image to be used as markers with Google maps so I can then use an if statement to switch between them.

```
var image = {
url: 'images/green20.png',
size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10)
  };
```

This is what I'm using for one of my markers. Which is later used here:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: locations[i][0]
  });
```

Is it possible to name the var image differently? E.g I also want to use orange20.png.

Somehow using something like:

```
if (locations[i][4]='vacant') {
icon: image (green20.png)
} else { 
icon: image (orange20.png)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, within the `for loop` itself you can change the `image` variable depending on anything you'd like.

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var image = {
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10)
    }

    if(locations[i][4] == 'vacant') {
      image.url = 'http://example.com/image1.jpg'
    } else {
      image.url = 'http://example.com/image2.jpg'
    }

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: locations[i][0]
  });
}
```

Comment: Cheers man, I'm a total noob when it comes to this. Where do I define the url?
    `for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      
        if(locations[i][4].value == 'vacant') {
         image = 'images/orange20.png'
       } else {
         image = 'images/green20.png'
       }`
That doesn't seem to be working for me, or do I define it at
`var image = {
    url: 'images/green20.png',
    url: 'images/orange20.png',`

Excuse the edits, kept pressing enter without shift!

Comment: @Berry see my updated answer, it's more or less the same as the original `image` object, only we're adding the `url` key in later.

Comment: The icon doesn't change, it remains as whichever image was first defined by `image.url =`. Do I need to define whatever is in `locations[i][4]=` or something?

Comment: @Berry That is your logic and needs to be written to suit your own needs - please provide some example `locations` data to give this question more context.

Comment: `var locations = [
      ['1 Allen Street', -41.292729, 174.782762, 4,'vacant'],
      ['1 Blair Street', -41.292933, 174.783575, 5,'tenant'],
      ['42 Cable Street', -41.291005, 174.780624, 3,'vacant'],
      ['10 Cambridge Terrace', -41.293740, 174.783840, 2,'tenant'],
      ['13 College Street', -41.296436, 174.781125, 1,'tenant']
   
    ];`

Comment: My mistake sortof, this was probably a syntax error try my updated answer.